# Calculation of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have problems with the following exercise:

> Let $\Omega=[-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}]$,
>   $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on
>   $\Omega$ and P the Lebesgue-measure.
>
> Let $X(\omega)=\omega^2$, $Y(\omega)=\omega^3$ $\forall \omega \in \Omega$.  Calculate $E[X|Y]=E[X|\sigma(Y)]$ and $E[Y|X]$.

My thoughts:

Let $Z:=E[E[X|Y]$

$E[Z]=E[X] \iff$ $\int_{A}Zd\mathbb{P} = \int_AXd\mathbb{P}$  $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$

$\Rightarrow$ $Z=X$ $a.s.$ $\Rightarrow$ $E[X|Y]=Y^\frac{2}{3}$?

E[Y|X] analog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X=\sqrt[3]{Y^2}$ hence $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable and $E(X\mid Y)=$ $____$.

In the other direction, assume you are given $X(\omega)$, what can you say about $\omega$? Use the answer to show that $E(Y\mid X)=0$.

Comment: Hi Did, thanks. So $E[X|Y] = \sqrt[3]{Y^2}$.But I don't understand your second hint for $E[Y|X]$

Comment: Assume you know that $X(\omega)=x$ (that is, you are given $x$ but not $\omega$). What is $\omega$?

Comment: Then $\omega = +- \sqrt{x}$. What does actually X is Y-measurable mean? That $\forall x \in X(\omega): X^{-1}(\omega) \in Y^{-1}(\omega)$?

Comment: Yes, $\omega=\pm\sqrt{x}$. What does this suggest regarding $E(Y\mid X)$? // "Actually", $X$ $\sigma(Y)$-measurable here means that $X$ is a measurable function of $Y$.

Comment: Then for every $x\in \Omega$: $(Y|X=x)$ $\in$ {$-\sqrt{x}^3,\sqrt{x}^3$} thus $E[Y|X]=0$. // But why can't you say: $Y=\sqrt{X}^3$ hence Y is X-measurable (since $x^\frac{3}{2}$ is a measurable function) so $E[Y|X]=\sqrt{X}^3$

Comment: Because it is not true that $Y=\sqrt{X}^3$... For example $P(\sqrt{X}^3\gt0)=1$ while $P(Y\lt0)\ne0$.

Comment: Oh I understand. But my argument for E[X|Y]=0 was right?

Comment: You mean, E(Y|X)=0, right? Then your argument goes in the right direction but it is incomplete: one also needs the density of X to be even.

Comment: P is the Lebesgue measure, so the density is 1?

Comment: The Lebesgue measure on Ω is not a probability.

Comment: But how can I calculate the density then?

Comment: The density is constant on Ω and must integrate to $1$ hence...

Comment: So the density of X is $\frac{3}{2}$.  But we need the density of $f_{Y|X}=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_{X}}$. If this is constant, then I could take the argument of above?

Comment: No, the density **of P** is 3/2 on the proper interval, the density of X is another matter. And no, one does not need the density $f_{X\mid Y}$ to solve the exercise (which is fortunate since there is no conditional density of X conditionally on Y).

Comment: But why do I need the density of X then?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X<x)=\mathbb{P}(\omega^2<x)=\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{x}<\omega<\sqrt{x})$=$\int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}$$3/2dy$=$3\sqrt{x}. So f_{X}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(3\sqrt{x})=\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: From some comments on, you seem to concentrate on densities of random variables. As already mentioned, these are not needed to solve the question.

Comment: You wrote: "one also needs the density of X to be even." So I thought I have to calculate the density of X. I'm a bit confused. What is the missing thing of my argument?

Comment: Yes, here the density of Y (not X) is even hence the distribution of Y is symmetric and this helps to compute E(Y|X), but one does not have to compute the density of Y. // OK, up to now you proposed only peripheral considerations (and confusion on the notions involved) but no direct attack to the problem, hence let me suggest that you write down your solution, if you think you have one, and we shall have something concrete to discuss. Deal?